# Comparing with SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio and having differences while table is the same

Tags: sql-server, compare

While comparing, I see that tables that are the same, come up in the Changes Detected tree. I see columns in the Source Object Definition with an empty entry in the Target Object Definition. And the same columns visa versa.

My question is: is there is a setting, that differences like this when enabled, not show this as a change?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Settings -> General -> Checkbox for  Ignore column order

Note : Settings from schema compare tab

Comment: Thanks for giving me this solution